# android application can run in emulator but it can't run in devices using apk

Tags: java, android

My app can run in emulator. Then I install my app in devices (Hp) but when I opened my app, my app is *force close* and say "application is not installed in your phone"

Can you help me how to fix my problem?

Comment: just check your minimum SDK version

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [hardware android debug](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)